# Filter hostvar by special propery

Tags: ansible

I have host.yml like this

```
---
  all:
    hosts:

      server-a:
        server_dc: "Hetzner"
        ansible_host: 192.168.1.1

      server-b:
        server_dc: "OVH"
        ansible_host: 192.168.1.2
```

And play book debug is:

```
- name: sample
  debug:
    var: hostvars
```

And all hostvars debug success.

How to get same hostvars **variable** but filtered. Any of that server_dc is equal `OVH`

I dont want to iterate for template, i just one new filtered variable that contain all other properies.

I need another variable that i debug see this output:

```
['server-b']
```

Comment: can you please post with a clear example of the output that you are expecting?

Answer (score 2):

This I believe meets your requirement (removing 'no_log: true', will result in the complete dictionary being printed in your playbook output):

```
- set_fact:
    filtered_hosts: "{{ filtered_hosts | default({}) | combine({item.key: item.value}) }}"
  when: "item.value.server_dc == 'OVH'"
  with_dict: "{{ hostvars }}"
  no_log: true
- debug:
    var: filtered_hosts
```